# Prove or disprove the following statement about natural numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove or disprove for the universe of natural numbers:

$\forall n_0\geq 1 \ \exists \alpha \ \forall j, \ 1\leq j\leq n_0 \ \exists k \colon \quad k\cdot j = \alpha -n_0$

Is there a way to choose $\alpha$, such that for any $j$, $1\leq j\leq n_0$, $j$ is a multiple of $\alpha-n_0$?

So far I've found out that $\alpha:=n_0+j$ would lead to $k\cdot j=j$ which is satisfied for $k=1$. However, this means that $\alpha$ depends on $j$, which we do not want. Is there a way to construct an $\alpha$ only depending on $n_0$ such that the upper condition is satisfied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $n_0$, you want to find $\alpha$ such that $\alpha-n_0$ is a multiple of $1,2,3,\ldots,n_0$, and this should be easy enough.

Comment: alpha = (product of numbers from 1 to n_0) + n_0.

Comment: @ndrizza Yes. Another way of writing it would be $\alpha=(n_0)!+n_0$.